# Div show/hide is not working inside partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view, based on the content of view bag I want to show the div and fade out after some second,for this I am using jQuery. everything is working fine if I put the code in main view. Unfortunately I want to have this pop up inside Partial view. code given below

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error_Msg_div" class=" " data-label="canccelled" data-left="0" data-top="0" data-width="0" data-height="0" style="display:block;position: absolute !important; left: 600px !important ;" >

       
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
        {
        <!-- Unnamed (Rectangle) -->
            <div id="error_text" class="ax_default label">

                <!-- Unnamed () -->
                <div id="error_msg" class="text">
                    <p><span>@ViewBag.Message</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div>
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
        {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("error");

                $("#error_Msg_div").show();
                $("#error_Msg_div").fadeOut(5000);

            </script>
        }
    </div>
```

here even the JavaScript `alert` is working fine. But the Show and Fade out is not working.

Comment: Could you make sure you include jQuery?

Comment: You could also chain the methods like `$('#error_Msg_div').show().fadeOut(5000);` (this has nothing to do with your problem, is just to improve readabiliy)

Comment: working for me. may be you just do not see that on the page. remove style: `style="display:block;position: absolute !important; left: 600px !important ;"` and see

Comment: @web2017 , u tried with partial view ?

Comment: @poc do you call partial-view with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Move you script outside (and after) the div you are attempting to operate on. Open chrome developer tools and post any remaining error you find in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Please find answer as below

```
<div id="error_Msg_div" class=" " data-label="canccelled" data-left="0" data-top="0" data-width="0" data-height="0" style="display:block;position: absolute !important; left: 600px !important ;">


    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
    {
    <!-- Unnamed (Rectangle) -->
        <div id="error_text" class="ax_default label">

            <!-- Unnamed () -->
            <div id="error_msg" class="text">
                <p><span>@ViewBag.Message</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ('@ViewBag.Message' == '') {

                alert("error");

                $("#error_Msg_div").show();
                $("#error_Msg_div").fadeOut(5000);
            }
        });

    </script>
```

you need call javascript function when view load

Comment: this is working only if I put the code in main view. I want this to be in Partial view.